# How to use a button to move between tabs in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using tabs in bootstrap:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="guide-tabs">
  <li class="list-group-item active"><a href="#link1"  data-toggle="tab">Link 1</a></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#link2"  data-toggle="tab">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="col-sm-8 tab-pane active" id="link1>Link 1 content </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8 tab-pane active" id="link2>Link 2 content </div>         
</div>
```

This works fine to switch tabs based on links in the `#guide-tabs` list.

I now want to add a button in the `#link1` content to move to the next tab:

```
 <div class="col-sm-8 tab-pane active" id="link1>
    Link 1 content
    <a href="#link2" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">Link 2</a>
  </div>
```

This code will move the tab on, but the `active` class in the list group doesn't change. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the href and data-toggle approach, your best bet may be to just do a straight javascript toggle. (Since tabs are a [Bootstrap JS component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).)

```
<script>
  $("#tab2Button").click(function() {
    $('#guide-tabs li:eq(1) a').tab('show');
  })
</script>
```

See: http://plnkr.co/edit/DdHLjgjK23KF8fJd1gMw

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar approach to @Hop's that will work for any number of tabs. A "continue" button is added to each tab pane to navigate to the next tab...

```
$('.cont').click(function(){
  var nextId = $(this).parents('.tab-pane').next().attr("id");
  $('[href=#'+nextId+']').tab('show');
})
```

http://www.bootply.com/130874